# Barra de informações estilo TV (semelhante a tag <marquee>)

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Preciso fazer uma barra de informações estilo dos canais de TV que fica passando da direita para esquerda. Tenho o texto que vem do banco de dados e como é um texto longo precisaria que fosse passando em loop.
Usarei em uma página da web.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo se vc não postar o código que já tem, não vai conseguir ajuda!

Comment: Sem postar o código é complicado, poderia até te sugerir usar algo improvável como `<marquee>` no seu código por exemplo...

Comment: O Stackoverflow não fornece código prontos

Comment: @RicardoPontual Esse elemento está obsoleto. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: @ValdeirPsr eu sei, por isso disse "*sugerir usar algo improvável*", acho que não entendeu o que eu quis dizer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como vc não botou mais detalhes na pergunta segue um modelo simples que pode te servir. Basicamente vc precisa criar um "container" com `overflow:hidden` e fazer a animação com `@keyframes`

```css
.txt {
    width: 10em;
    height: 1.5em;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.txt span {
    padding-left: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: texto 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes texto {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="txt"><span>URGENTE!!! - <strong>Bolso Mito vai te pegar</strong> se vc não colocar o código na pergunta!</span></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tem o plugin jquery.marquee que usa css3 para fazer a animação, como o elemento marquee é obsoleto acho que esse é o melhor caminho.
Encontrei no codepen um exemplo https://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/qgutw

```js
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    duration: 5000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 50,
    //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: 'left',
    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
    duplicated: true
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<div class="marquee">jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world</div>
```