# Como fazer um elemento cruzar a tela de forma contínua e sempre visível?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animação

Tenho uma animação em CSS de um elemento que cruza toda a tela, da direita para a esquerda, continuamente de forma infinita:

```css
#slider{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   right: 0;
   background: red;
   width: 150px;
   height: 50px;
   animation: anima 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes anima{
   from {right: 0}
   to {right: 100%}
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Repare que o elemento, ao sumir da tela à esquerda (`right: 100%`), ele volta para a posição `right: 0`, ou seja, para o lado direito inicial e assim sucessivamente.

Não é esse efeito que eu gostaria. Queria que o elemento ficasse cruzando a tela de forma contínua, e não voltando para a posição inicial, e que, quando parte dele saísse da tela à esquerda, essa parte já aparecesse do lado direito; e também não que ele começasse a aparecer novamente do lado direito quando ele sumir todo do lado esquerdo, como faz o saudoso `marquee`. Ou seja, o elemento estará sempre visível, seja ele todo ou parte dele.

Seria algo assim, como ilustro na imagem abaixo como um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer isso apenas com CSS? Uma solução com JavaScript também seria válida, mas não consegui pensar numa forma de chegar a esse resultado. Talvez tenha que clonar o elemento, ou usar um pseudo-elemento `::before` ou `::after`... Alguma ideia?

Comment: Uma referencia que vai te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698758/css-infinite-horizontal-scroll-with-keyframe

Comment: Agora que entendi direito o que vc precisava, até achei essa outra resposta, mas ela é praticamente igual a que eu tinha dado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292960/barra-de-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-estilo-tv-semelhante-a-tag-marquee/ Acho que apenas com CSS a única forma seria com pseudo elemento mesmo com dois elementos iguais, pois ele não pode estar em dois lugares ao mesmo tempo.... Apesar que para esse exemplo seu em particular daria para fazer com SVG (digo apenas um cubo atravessando a tela, se for pra ficar idêntico a pergunta, com SVG tb daria), mas indo o before/after

Comment: Cara olha que interessante, sei que o SVG não deve ser a melhor opção, mas sei que vc gosta dessas paradas, olha como a animação no SVG parece mais suave! Ela não da nanhuma agarradinha, vai fluida sem "tremidinha"...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é colocar como `after` um elemento igual distanciado à direita pelo tamanho inteiro da tela com `left: 100vw`. Assim quando o elemento começar a sumir pela esquerda o distanciado à direita aparece na mesma proporção que o primeiro já sumiu.

Exemplo (apenas acrescentei o `#slider::after`):

```css
#slider{
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px;
   right: 0;
   background: red;
   width: 150px;
   height: 50px;
   animation: anima 3s linear infinite;
}

#slider::after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   left:100vw;
   background: red;
   width: 150px;
   height: 50px;
}

@keyframes anima{
   from {right: 0}
   to {right: 100%}
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Resposta bem criativa, ficou bem massa!

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Mt obg! :))))

Comment: @Sam É isso! Estamos cá uns para os outros! :D

Answer (score 8):

Tb é possível usando um `linear-gradiente` e mudando o `background-position`

```css
#slider{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  animation: anima 3s linear infinite;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,red 75px, #fff 75px, #fff calc(100% - 75px), red calc(100% - 75px));
}
@keyframes anima{
  from {background-position-x: 100vw;}
  to {background-position-x: 0vw;}
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Animando o `dashoffset` de uma `line` `svg`

Repare que a animação é bem fluida, não tem travamento ou "tremidinhas" no elemento quanto ele se movimenta pela tela.

```css
svg {
 stroke-dashoffset: 75px;
 animation: nome 3s infinite linear;
}
line {
 stroke:red; 
 stroke-width: 150px;
}
@keyframes nome {
 0% {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
 }
 100% {
  stroke-dashoffset: 100vw;
 }
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="50px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line stroke-dasharray="150, calc(100vw - 150px)" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0"></line>
</svg>
```

Comment: Legal, mas não bem isso. Veja que o elemento só aparece à direita quando some todo à esquerda. É exatamente isso que eu não queria rs :D

Comment: @sam vou reler a pergunta rss

Comment: Ficou legal, mas note que antes do elemento tocar na lateral esquerda, já aparece outro à direita.

Comment: @Sam resolvido, eu que vacilei com as contas rss

Comment: O problema é que vc está trabalhando apenas no fundo vermelho. A div terá conteúdo. O vermelho é apenas para ver o elemento no exemplo.

Comment: @Sam sem problemas, eu estava só testando as possibilidades  

Answer (score 3):

**3°opção** 

**Vantagens**: Mais performático

**Motivo**: Faz uso da feature `transform` do CSS, não faz **reflows** para cada iteração da animação.

> Obs: O **algoritmo de renderização do browser (Render Tree, CSSOM)** não precisa recalcular o posicionamento do elemento a cada iteração da animação.

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
.carousel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, .25fr);
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: translate3d(75%,0,0);
  animation: anima 3s linear infinite
}
.carousel:before,
.carousel:after {
  content: ".";
  display: inherit;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,1)
}
.carousel:after {
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0)
}
@keyframes anima{
  from{transform: translate3d(75%,0,0)}
  to {transform: translate3d(-25%,0,0)}
}
```

```html
<aside class="carousel"></aside>
```

Answer (score -1):

Estava procurando uma forma de fazer uma imagem se mover,
Gracas ao seu código eu consegui, Porém mudei algumas coisas. Segue o código:

CSS

```
#slider{
    position: absolute;
    scroll-padding-bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
    background: transparent;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: anima 20s linear infinite;
 }
 
 @keyframes anima{
    from {right: 0}
    to {right: 100%}
 }
```

HTML

```
<img src="img/well.jpg" id="slider" alt="Instalador de painel Solar">
```

Comment: Seu código não responde a pergunta, no loop a sua imagem inicia a direita, já dentro da página, a atenção aqui é que o elemento comece a direita fora da tela, e termine na esquerda, fora da tela a cada loop