# É Possivel fazer isso com javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso chegar no resultado da imagem. se puderem me ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Amigo, [veja este exemplo](http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/animacao-de-texto-css3.html) e me diga se te ajuda. É apenas com CSS

Comment: Duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292960/barra-de-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-estilo-tv-semelhante-a-tag-marquee/ e de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11862/como-fazer-um-marquee-sem-a-tag-marquee

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma de fazer esse letreiro é utilizar a propriedade CSS ['animation'](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation) e a regra ['@keyframes'](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), que controla as etapas intermediárias em uma sequência de animação, em conjunto da função ['translateX()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX) que reposiciona um elemento horizontalmente.

```css
.letreiro {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.letreiro p {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: rolagem 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rolagem {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="letreiro">
  <p>G1 - O Portal de notícias.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado augusto, mas eu necessito que quando chegue na ultima letra a animação finalize. será que tem como.

Comment: @CaioJfmg, na propriedade `animation` apague o atributo `infinite` que a animação irá executar apenas uma vez.

Comment: Augusto, eu estou me referindo ao seguinte: na sua animação, no finalzinho dela fica um espaço em branco. preciso que a animação continue mas quando chegar na última letra, essa letra teria que permanecer alinhada com a linha right da div. não poderia aparecer aquele espaço em branco. compreende. assim : notícias |      e não   espaço em branco |

Comment: Você quer que termine a animação quando o ponto final aparecer na tela?

Comment: @CaioJfmg: No seletor `.letreiro p` sete a propriedade `transform` para `translateX(-50%);` e na regra `rolagem` no atributo `100%` faça  `transform: translateX(-50%);`.

Comment: Funcionou Augusto. mais uma vez agradeço a boa vontade. tenha um bom dia. ;)

Comment: Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.